# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the MySQL code I am using on the server to create a table...

```
CREATE TABLE brand_names (
    id int(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    brand_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_company_id int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    last_modified_on timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE KEY brand_name (brand_name),
    FULLTEXT KEY name (brand_name)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=225 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I am trying to replicate the same table in Android by using...

```
CREATE TABLE brand_names (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    brand_name text NOT NULL,
    parent_company_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    last_modified_on datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT
)
```

However, I am getting this exception...

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ON": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE brand_names (_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, brand_name text NOT NULL, parent_company_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', last_modified_on datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT);
```

So there seems to be something wrong around the `ON` part. (NB - All I am trying to achieve with the ON clause is to make it so that when the row is updated, the last_modified_on datetime will be automatically set to the current time.

I've looked at this [SQLite page](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions), and it looks like my syntax is correct, but clearly something is wrong so I'm a bit stumped. Can anyone help resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct one is,

```
CREATE TABLE brand_names (
    _id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    brand_name text NOT NULL,
    parent_company_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    last_modified_on datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

You are using **ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT** in the end which is wrong syntax.

The last_modified_on datetime will be automatically set to the current time by using DEFAULT `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

What you have seen from the [SQLite doc](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions) is totally different from what you want to achieve.

The following query will work assuming you have a  parent table with id parent_company_id -

```
CREATE TABLE brand_names(_id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
brand_name text NOT NULL, parent_company_id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
last_modified_on datetime NOT NULL REFERENCES parent(parent_company_id) 
ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT);
```

This will update the parent_company_id (*the parent key of the foreign key constraint*) column of the parent record without breaking referential integrity between the two tables `parent` and `brand_names`.

An `ON UPDATE` action is only taken if the values of the parent key are modified so that the new parent key values are not equal to the old. So this is used  to configure actions that take place when modifying the parent key values of existing rows (ON UPDATE). They are associated with each foreign key in an SQLite database.

Comment: … that ON UPDATE would require a trigger in SQLite.

Comment: @CL. - Indeed! Forgot to mention, it is used as a trigger to auto updated the row(s) without breaking referential integrity. Thanks!